# Linked DataFlow block completion is not working

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have a `BroadcastBlock` linked to `ActionBlock`. When I call "complete" sequentially on both the `BroadcastBlock` and `ActionBlock`, it is not working. Whereas just calling "complete" on `BroadCastBlock` alone is working.

```
public class ActionTester
{
    private readonly ActionBlock<int> _action;
    private readonly BroadcastBlock<int> _input;

    public ActionTester()
    {
        _input = new BroadcastBlock<int>(null);
        _action = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Process(i));

        _input.LinkTo(_action, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }

    public void Post(int i) => _input.Post(i);

    public async Task Process(int i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        _input.Complete();
        _action.Complete(); // When this is removed, program is working as expected
    }

    public Task Completion => _action.Completion;
}
```

The test code is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var actor = new ActionTester();

    actor.Post(5);
    actor.Post(7);

    actor.Complete();
    actor.Completion.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.Read();
}
```

When `_action.Complete()` is present (commented line), code moves past `actor.Completion.wait()` and "Finished" is getting displayed. If I remove `_aciton.Complete()`, the posted values are displayed properly and then "Finished" is written.

When dataflow blocks are linked, should we just call "Complete" of the root block only? Setting `PropagateCompletion` to true/false has no effect.

**Solution**

Resolved by waiting for the root block completion

```
public void Complete()
{
    _input.Complete();
    _input.Completion.Wait();
    _action.Complete(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When dataflow blocks are linked, should we just call "Complete" of the root block only?

Yes, this is exactly what should you do.

If you do propagate the `Completion`, then you do **not** need to complete `_actionBlock` by yourself - it will be completed after all the items from buffer are processed. After you do complete the action block, it wouldn't accept any new messages, so the described behavior is expected and valid.

Comment: When "PropogateCompletion" is set to false, shouldn't we call complete on all the linked blocks? In my example, even if I set PropagateCompletion to false, it was not working if I have the another call for complete on the linked block.

Comment: If you complete the second block **before** all the messages are sent from first to second, second will discard all of them. So, if you do not propagate the completion, you need to handle it by yourself.